# Why can't I break or place blocks in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing on a single player modded survival and I went to check the forums for help with one mod. When I got back on my game I couldn't mine or place blocks and I've tried switching to /gamemode 0 but this only happened in my modded survival. I can still place and break blocks in vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: you probably switched to adventure mode instead of survival mode at some point.

Comment: You should check out the related questions list on the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to do that means you're in adventure mode. Remember that now you can use /gamemode a, s, or c to change your gamemode to avoid things like this happening again.

Comment: Or /gamemode 0 for survival, 1 for creative, 2 for adventure, and 3 for spectator. Far more intuitive for me.

Answer (score -2):

type in /gamemode s
you are in adventure mode it will turn adventure mode off